# How to save graphics created by the as3 drawing api to local disk and then reopen it

Tags: actionscript-3

I have created an application which can draw shapes using the as3 drawing api. Now i want to save these drawings to local disk and then open the file later for further editing.

How can i do that ?? Is converting the objects drawn to bitmaps will do it ?? will i lose any quality or something if i convert my movie clips to bitmaps...?? or is there any other way to do what i want to achieve.

Also i don't want to convert the drawings to jpegs or any other image formats.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The AS3 drawing API is vector based. Bitmaps are rasterized images at specific resolutions (you'd never be able to edit them). You'll have to track what calls you make to the drawing API, save that information, then load that later and redo the API calls specified from the saved data.

Comment: @Cameron - There is an easier way, please see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at readGraphicsData():

> In Flash Player 11.6 and Adobe AIR 3.6 and later you can use the
>   Graphics class’s readGraphicsData() method to obtain a data
>   representation of the vector graphics content of a display object.
>   This can be used to create a snapshot of a graphic to save, copy,
>   create a spritesheet at run time, and more.
>
> Calling the readGraphicsData() method returns a Vector instance
>   containing IGraphicsData objects. These are the same objects used to
>   draw vector graphics with the drawGraphicsData() method.

Source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS749610B4-4709-4f75-BBA0-650BF52623CA.html

Here is the documentation for [readGraphicsData()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#readGraphicsData()) and [drawGraphicsData()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#drawGraphicsData()).

You can also see an example and some discussion of it here: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=5013

Comment: Thanks a ton... :)

I think this will do... especially the example link at bytearray.org is exactly what i was looking for.... I guess i'll be able to save this as a bytearray or something and then reopen it later.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example on how you can save shape data and load it back in.

To make it shorter I'm using a SharedObject, but it is the same process for using `FileStream.writeObject` instead of SharedObject.

```
//These are all the classes potentially used by Graphics:
import flash.display.GraphicsBitmapFill;
import flash.display.IGraphicsData;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.filters.BitmapFilter;
import flash.geom.Vector3D;
import flash.display.GraphicsEndFill;
import flash.display.GraphicsGradientFill;
import flash.display.GraphicsPath;
import flash.display.GraphicsShaderFill;
import flash.display.Shader;
import flash.display.ShaderData;
import flash.display.GraphicsSolidFill;
import flash.display.GraphicsStroke;
import flash.display.GraphicsTrianglePath;

//an object to draw to:
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(mySprite);

//to automatically serialize the graphics, we need to register all classes involved
    registerClassAlias("flash.display.IGraphicsData", IGraphicsData);
    registerClassAlias("flash.display.GraphicsBitmapFill", GraphicsBitmapFill);
    registerClassAlias("flash.geom.Matrix", Matrix);    
    registerClassAlias("flash.display.BitmapData", BitmapData);
    registerClassAlias("flash.geom.Rectangle", Rectangle);
    registerClassAlias("flash.geom.Point", Point);
    registerClassAlias("flash.utils.ByteArray", ByteArray);
    registerClassAlias("flash.geom.ColorTransform", ColorTransform);
    registerClassAlias("flash.filters.BitmapFilter", BitmapFilter);
    registerClassAlias("flash.geom.Vector3D", Vector3D);
    registerClassAlias("flash.display.GraphicsEndFill", GraphicsEndFill);
    registerClassAlias("flash.display.GraphicsGradientFill", GraphicsGradientFill);
    registerClassAlias("flash.display.GraphicsPath", GraphicsPath);
    registerClassAlias("flash.display.GraphicsShaderFill", GraphicsShaderFill);
    registerClassAlias("flash.display.Shader", Shader);
    registerClassAlias("flash.display.ShaderData", ShaderData);
    registerClassAlias("flash.display.GraphicsSolidFill", GraphicsSolidFill);
    registerClassAlias("flash.display.GraphicsStroke", GraphicsStroke);
    registerClassAlias("flash.display.GraphicsTrianglePath", GraphicsTrianglePath);

    //shared object to use
    var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myShapes");

    //check if the shared object already has data
    if (so.data && so.data.shapes) {

        try{
            //load the existing shape data into our sprite
            mySprite.graphics.drawGraphicsData(so.data.shapes);
        }catch(err){
            trace(err.toString());
        }
    }

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicky);


function clicky(e:Event):void {

    //let's draw a random circle
    mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF * Math.random(), Math.random());
    mySprite.graphics.drawCircle(Math.random() * stage.stageWidth, Math.random() * stage.stageHeight, Math.random() * 500);
    mySprite.graphics.endFill();

    //let's update the shared object to reflect our updated graphics
    so.data.shapes = mySprite.graphics.readGraphicsData();
    so.flush();
}
```

Comment: Cool! Definitely better than doing it by hand.